# How can I hook opengl es in android to get the number of draw call?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I am making a simple Unity Game in android platform.Performance test is neccesary.I have got some performance data like cpu, battery, pss_total, fps, mono heap size...But the unity does not provide a API to get the number of draw call in a certain mount of time, or the number of draw call to draw a material.

So I have to be self-dependance.I know that Unity draw its game using opengl es in android platform.In opengl es, it uses five functions to deal with this matter: glDrawArrays, glDrawElements, glDrawArraysInstance, glDrawElementsInstance, glDrawRangeElemnts...If I know how many times these functions are called, then I know the number of draw call.And this is where the titles coms from.Somebody tells me to hook these functions, but I don't know how to do it at all.

Or if somebody know other ways to get this informatino, I am willing to try it.

Comment: You can try using some graphics profilers, like GAPID or Snapdragon Profiler. I think Mali and PowerVR also have some of those. And they show the drawcalls per frame, among other things.

Comment: That is pretty much helpful for me.Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting Unity3D project to Android project, and use Android's profiling tool to get the information. Further more, the Android Studio is open sourced, including the profiling tool, you can get the hooking code there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,bro. Android studio is  too big to search for the code. But it's a nice alternative choice, I will try it if there is no other way.